# Android MotionEvent Consistency Guarantees

Tags: android, android-view

The section entitled *Consistency Guarantees* in the documentation for the Android `MotionEvent` class indicates that views should be able to handle anomalous situations, such as receiving an `ACTION_DOWN` without first having received and `ACTION_UP`. Does this mean that a view should be able to tolerant any conceivable anomalous situation, such as receiving an `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` without first receiving an `ACTION_DOWN`, or an `ACTION_MOVE` without first an `ACTION_DOWN`? Does `MotionEvent` have any guarantees?

Comment: I have the same question, and found this in the docs - "Motion events are always delivered to views as a consistent stream of events." AND "While the framework tries to deliver consistent streams of motion events to views, it cannot guarantee it."  Talk about inconsistent! I think we need someone from the development team to help out with this one.